# Opening a samba share in emacs

Tags: samba, nautilus, gvfs

I am using emacs-snapshot, and I added an application shortcut to my `.local/share/applications/emacs-snapshot.desktop` :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Emacs Snapshot (GTK)
GenericName=Emacs
Comment=GNU Emacs Snapshot Text Editor
Exec=/usr/bin/emacs-snapshot-gtk
TryExec=emacs-snapshot
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=emacs-snapshot
Categories=Development;Utility;TextEditor;
MimeType=text/plain;
```

When I browse my folders (Nautilus 3.4.2) and right click on files on my local disk, I can choose Open With -> Emacs Snapshot (GTK):
[image: emacs]

However, when I browse to a samba share (`smb://data/mydata/`) and click on a file, I am not given an option to open it in Emacs - even if I click "Open with other application -> Show other applications":

[image: Open with other applications]

How do I fix it?

Further info:

- OS: Debian Wheezy
- Emacs from http://emacs.naquadah.org/ : emacs-snapshot-gtk
- the output of `ldd /usr/bin/emacs-snapshot-gtk`: http://pastebin.com/0Rz9mKQA

Comment: Explanation: Samba mounts in Nautilus are provided by [Gvfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS), a pseudo-filesystem library used by Gnome applications. Nautilus isn't detecting Emacs as supporting GVFS (either because your Emacs doesn't have it or because Nautilus doesn't support it). Emacs GVFS support is a compile-time option; what distribution are you using, which Emacs package (if there's a choice), and what is the output of `ldd /usr/bin/emacs` (or `/ldd /usr/bin/emacs-gtk` or whichever is applicable)?

Comment: @Gilles I added more info to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the way the share was mounted (GVFS), as hinted by Gilles. In order for my network folder to work "properly", I had to install cifs-utils

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

And

```
mount -t cifs -o domain=mydomain,uid=myuid,forceuid,gid=mygid,forcegid //server/share /shared
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can do this quite the way you expect.  What I do is I create a symlink to .gvfs called network in my home folder.

```
cd ~
ln -s .gvfs network
```

Then browse to network in Nautilus which will contain the network shares created in Nautilus.  You should be able to open the file in emacs from there.